# Equivalent of \chapter[title]{title} in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, context

In LaTeX, one can use `\chapter[A]{B}`, such that, in the table of contents, "A" appears, but in the actual page where the chapter begins, "B" appears. This allows one to print different text in the table of contents. What is the equivalent of this in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\starttext
\placecontent
\startchapter[title=B,list=A]
\input tufte
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```